# Drawing a graph with two functions, include the cosine function

Tags: pgfplots

First, I would like this plot to be in radians. I want a plot of two functions. `$y = \cos x$` and
`$y = 1 - \cos x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \pi $`.

I wrote the following LaTex code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1,legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot {cos( x * pi))}; 
\addplot {1 - cos( x * pi))}; 
\addlegendentry{$ cos( x * pi)) $} 
\addlegendentry{$ 1 -  cos( x * pi)) $} 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For the first curve, I got a straight line similar to $y 0 1$. For the second curve, I got
a straight line similar to $y = 0$. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If domain is given in radians, you need to convert function argument to radians with axis option `trig format=rad`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid,
             legend pos=outer north east,
             trig format=rad,
             domain=0:1,
             xtick={0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1},
             xticklabels={0,$\pi/4$,$\pi/2$,$3\pi/4$,$\pi$},
             no marks]
\addplot {cos(pi*x)};
\addplot {1 - cos(pi*x)};
    \legend{$\cos(x)$, $1 -  \cos(x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]